# putting transform:scale() in js

Tags: javascript, css

How would I put

```
 transform:scale(0.5);
```

in css to javascript

I have tried

```
document.getElementById().style.transform = "scale(0.5)";
```

It didn't work.

Comment: It does work if you provide a valid ID in `getElementById`. You can edit your question and add your code in a snippet.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros I have no clue how I messed it up but I did. It's working now lol.